# SQL Server: How to update a table with values from another table

Tags: sql-server, sql-update

I have two tables.
Users1:

```
UserID HolidayCity ValidFrom    ValidTo
1      NULL        '1900-01-01' '2017-05-09'
1      NULL        '2017-05-09' NULL
2      NULL        '1900-01-01' '2017-05-09'
2      NULL        '2017-05-09' NULL
```

Users2:

```
UserID CityID
1      33
2      55
```

I need to update HolidayCity column from the first table with the values in CityID column from the second table for each UserID, but only those records, **where ValidTo IS NULL**, so that the resulting table Users1 would be:

```
UserID HolidayCity ValidFrom    ValidTo
1      NULL        '1900-01-01' '2017-05-09'
1      33          '2017-05-09' NULL
2      NULL        '1900-01-01' '2017-05-09'
2      55          '2017-05-09' NULL
```

Can you please tell me how to do that?

Comment: Thank you all for quick answers. They are all practically the same and they work for me.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is a simple `inner join`

```
update u
  set u.holidaycity=c.cityid
from users1 u
  inner join users2 c
    on u.userid = c.userid
   and u.validto is null
```

Answer (score 3):

The simple Way to copy the content from one table to other is as follow:

```
UPDATE table2 
SET table2.col1 = table1.col1, 
table2.col2 = table1.col2,
...
FROM table1, table2 
WHERE table1.memberid = table2.memberid
```

Comment: I'd advise you to use ANSI joins, the code you have there is pretty outdated. Have a read here: https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins

Comment: @Leonidas199x  yes i check tankyou for advise

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
update a

 set a.HolidayCity = b.CityID
FROM         Users1 AS a INNER JOIN
                      Users2 AS b ON a.UserId = b.UserId
WHERE     (a.ValidTo IS NULL)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE      U1
SET         U1.HolidayCity  =   U2.CityID
FROM        Users1          AS  U1
INNER JOIN  Users2          AS  U2  ON  U2.UserId = U1.UserId
WHERE       U1.ValidTo  IS NULL
```

If you have any questions about the above code, happy to expand, but this is a simple update format.